# How to use JBrowserDriver for Whatsapp Web?

Tags: web-scraping, webdriver

My client requires me to monitor incoming whatsapp messages to process Purchase Order that sent by his agents on the field. They used to use Telegram for that matter, but since our government banned Telegram (like a month ago), they look for solution using whatsapp.

Currently I'm still in the state of researching the right solution, so I use **JBrowserDriver** from [here](https://github.com/MachinePublishers/jBrowserDriver)

My code currently is like below snippet:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JBrowserDriver driver = new JBrowserDriver(Settings.builder()
            .headless(false)
            .userAgent(UserAgent.CHROME)
            .javascript(true)
            .ssl("trustanything").build());
    driver.get("https://web.whatsapp.com/");
}
```

From the snippet above, I deliberately set **headless** to **false** so I can see in popup browser, to check whether whatsapp web is properly opened.

My problem is: whatsapp web seems to understand that the request I made isn't from the real browser (e.g. IE, Firefox, Chrome and etc)... so Instead a page that has QR code for login, I got redirected to a page that recommend me to use REAL browser.

How can we go around this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Try how you can use http://machinepublishers.github.io/jBrowserDriver/com/machinepublishers/jbrowserdriver/UserAgent.html in order to simulate being a real browser

Comment: I did set UserAgent as CHROME (check my code above), but doesn't work, I wanna try to use other params e.g. family, vendor and etc, but I don't know what to put in each value

Comment: One suggestion: compare the headers passed between  the components using a proxy and add those that are missing

Comment: You mean I must create a proxy server and connect my jbrowser to wassap trough it?

Comment: Yes, either use some readymade proxy like Membrane SOA or fiddler or enable http level logging

Comment: I installed Fiddler from Telerik ... and it captured browser traffics nicely... but I cannot capture JBrowserDriver traffic, maybe because I'm still new to this thing... any help would appreciated

Comment: Nvm... its settled ... I managed to use Fiddler thanks :)